# Alias a whole table in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ___Bookings 
INNER JOIN ___Rooms  ON ___Bookings.BOO_RoomId=___Rooms.ROO_Id 
INNER JOIN ___Kardex AS ka ON ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId=ka.KDX_Id 
LEFT JOIN ___Kardex AS kb ON ___Bookings.BOO_BillingId=kb.KDX_Id 
WHERE BOO_Id=224
```

This query works like a charm but give me the same column names because it makes a `JOIN` on the same table `___Kardex`.

Do I need an alias ?

How can I change thats please ?

Comment: you already have alises. `ka` and `kb`.

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Yes, explicitly state which columns you need from ka and kb with aliases.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is give the alias in the SELECT and not use the *. This is a little more work but it gives the results that you want.

like this

```
SELECT ka.Col1 as 'kacol1', kb.Col1 as 'kbCol1' 
FROM .....
```

You need to do this for each column

Comment: Please, don't use single quotes for table or column aliases. It works in some DBMS but it's a really bad habit.